# Is there a way to remove force_classic_login parameter?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When i request to sign in with my IG app, it automatically sends the user this weird login:

[image: Branded new login!]

And this URL is generated:
"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize%3Fclient_id....."

I've noticed that if i remove the parameter **force_classic_login=** it takes me to the new branded one:

[image: Branded new login!]

Does someone know how to control it from SDK ? thanks !