# Will be Instagram login totally deprecated?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram announced the **Instagram Platform API deprecation**:

*"To continuously improve Instagram users' privacy and security, we are accelerating the deprecation of Instagram API Platform"*

Their documentation and changelog says to refer to **new Instagram Graph API**.

Is it clear that many, almost every old endpoints are now deprecated, but nothing is said about login functionality.

The "new Instagram Graph API" seems to refer only to business oriented behaviour, so my question is: are they deprecating also Instagram Login feature for authentication?

FYI:

- https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/
- https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Comment: Diego D, It's been 2 month since it has been asked. any information about it?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB yep, I added information as answer below ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What I can say about this, after two months of investigation, is YES, Instagram login will be totally deprecated.**

This is not directly said into official news, but official news announced "Instagram API Platform Deprecation" and Instagram login is under that platform, that will be totally deprecated.

Another point is that since some weeks, instagram login is no more working as before due to the error *"parameter present into the redirect URL: force_classic_login"*

- [Is there a way to remove force_classic_login parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966453/is-there-a-way-to-remove-force-classic-login-parameter)
- https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/issues/255/

Seems Instagram is adding this parameter into redirect URL to force "classic login view" and this classic login view is causing issues on some devices due to cookie error management.

Facebook direction is pretty clear: they want to move everything from "user oriented" to "business oriented". So developers now should build apps for companies where they can use Facebook login, along with "Instagram product".
So who will use those apps will click on "Facebook login" and during permissions they will be asked to share Instagram scopes.
To better understand this flow, see official screencast here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started#screencast

Comment: That seems to be my understanding too.

Comment: It becomes interesting that not all Instagram accounts associate with Facebook account. I'm wondering how Facebook can unify both into one login button without confusing people.

Answer (score 0):

According to my findings, it won't be deprecated. To have the Instagram login, we need to have access to Instagram's `basic` scope API (for regular accounts and not the business ones only). Currently, this scope with support for regular users is only available on the old Instagram's developer platform.

But according to [this document by Facebook](https://diigo.com/0eh52n) this functionality will be added to Graph API in early 2019 (which has not delivered yet at the time of this writing) and the old API will be deprecated in early 2020. Here is the quote from Facebook's doc:

> Support for Non-Business Profiles [FUTURE]: Basic permissioning for non-business profiles will be supported in early 2019.

I also have a more detailed response on the process of review verification [in another related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55871205/1573477).