# ios - instagram login with new instagram graph api?

Tags: ios, authentication, instagram, instagram-api, submission

Instagram depreciates old Instagram Platform API. Graph API, extensively involved with facebook, is presented. But as far as I understand, it is not a replacement.

I only plan to use instagram for login purposes, like facebook login, in my app. However, I cant find a way to implement that with new graph api. Is it possible?

*Note: I submitted a client with old platform api, but cant get a response for 2 weeks and counting.*

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

With new Instagram Graph API, there is no Instagram login, if you have a converted your Instagram account to business account and connected to a facebook page, then you can login with that facebook account to retrieve that Instagram account, info, posts and stories.

Graph API is not a direct replacement for the Legacy APIs, I dont think anymore Legacy API is getting approved

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat, we submitted the Instagram app months ago, today it's still "pending review" - and the new Graph API has no way to get user profile information and requires the user to login with Facebook anyway

It isn't clear on the legacy API page , but app's are not getting approved for legacy API anymore

someone has a detailed answer here : [Will be Instagram login totally deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757271/will-be-instagram-login-totally-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late, but I'm going to share our findings here as well hoping it clears things out for others facing the same issue. My original post is available in [this Auth0 community thread](https://community.auth0.com/t/instagram-login-is-deprecated-and-the-documentation-on-auth0-is-broken/24122)

> I followed up the old API’s Instruction and generated a set of client
>   key and secret. Then created a video demo of the app and submitted a
>   review request on the old Instagram platform clearing out that I’m
>   going to use this API only for the login process and just defining the
>   basic scope to be reviewed. (Again all this happened on the old
>   Instagram platform and not the new Facebook graph platform).
>
> After around 24 hours, they have approved my request: image
>   [image]
>
> I also figured out that the problem on the base scope on Facebook’s graph
>   API (I stated above), will be resolved soon (early 2019) at least as
>   far as they have promised in [this document](https://diigo.com/0eh52n), which gives about a year
>   time window before the old basic scope’s deprecation. Using the old
>   API works perfectly inside the Auth0, but none of the scopes (other
>   than the default selected basic) will be applied.

Also here is the quote from Facebook's announcement linked above:

> Support for Non-Business Profiles [FUTURE]: Basic permissioning for non-business profiles will be supported in early 2019.