# Login with Instagram in iOS app using Instagram new graph API

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

How can we achieve login with the Instagram feature in iOS application with new Instagram graph API? They are deprecating the old APIs and they have suggested moving to New graph API.

I didn't find proper details on documentation which is located at below path:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Here is the same question but didn't get clear details from that question:
[ios - instagram login with new instagram graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235291/ios-instagram-login-with-new-instagram-graph-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios - instagram login with new instagram graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235291/ios-instagram-login-with-new-instagram-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Instagram Graph Api is only available for Instagram business accounts.for this you need to  create an app in your facebook developer account .You also need to and add instagram from the products section in your facebook app dashboard check the below screenshots 
[image: Screen_Shot_2018-08-07_at_5.47.36_PM.png]
These APIs do not support regular personal profiles If you are interested in the consumer (non-business) use cases that involve the Instagram login You can follow [the official instgram developer portal](http://www.instagram.com/developer/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the new Facebook Graph API doesn't provide `instagram_basic` scope for regular users. So the only way to have login functionality is through Instagram's old API platform.

However, this functionality is [announced to be released in early 2019](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/), one year before announced deprecation date of the old platform's basic scope.

I also have a more detailed response on the process of review verification [in another related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55871205/1573477).