# Integrating Social Login with Instagram basic display api

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

While reading [instagram basic display api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) documentation I get the sense that we cannot use this api for authentication. As they write under the limitation as:

> Authentication — Instagram Basic Display is not an authentication
> solution. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your
> app users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication
> solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead.

But looking at their [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference) I get they provide oauth tokens and authentication flow /scopes.
Their [getting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) also list down steps to setup app. Anyone please explain what I am missing there ? I am looking for social login solution using instagram, thanks.

Comment: I've recently been looking into this too, and it seems that the permission to use Instagram as a login option was removed earlier this year. It's now only to be used *after* login (via another method, of course) to link a user's account on your site with their Instagram account. It looks like this process started a couple of years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757271/will-be-instagram-login-totally-deprecated

Comment: @JoLoCo thanks for the link I was looking for reasonable answer